# How to open actual folder that is symlinked (with "real" path) on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, symbolic-link, file-shortcut

I have setup some symlinks  on my system using a script. I actually want to use these symlinks like a shortcut so that when I open the symlink in windows explorer it takes me to the real folder, not the fake folder!

So I want to open

```
C:\user\username\deep\path\to\folder\target
```

rather than

```
C:\user\username\symlinkname
```

I think that in reality I should be using shortcuts rather than symlinks but they are not as easy to create using a script (especially on my locked down machine at work).

Comment: The behavior you're describing indeed is that of link rather than a symlink. Using the context menu of the Windows Explorer to create them should be easy enough? Why do you need to crate them using a script?

Comment: I've got about 60 to create and the folders are very deeply nested. I also have to rename all the shortcuts after creating them. None of this is hard, just doing it 60 times is time consuming

Comment: There are several questions on StackExchange that deal with creating links using batch. That said, maybe you could improve your workflow? Why do you need the original path in the Windows "address" bar? Why is it insufficient to see the symlink path?

Comment: I get odd behaviour when using the symlink. when running a watch npm job for example the watch does not work, tests do not re-run when a file changes. There were other odd behaviours as well. All the answers about creating shortcuts won't work on my locked down work PC.

Comment: Talk to your IT about it? It does sound odd that NPM wouldn't be able to pick them up. On the other hand creating 60 shortcuts to arbitrary directories sounds like you might be able to improve the structure as a whole. If you are able to run NPM it would be odd that you can't run a batch or VBS. It might be that your locked down WS is responsible for NPM showing an odd behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can call this script from cmd in a symlinked folder
to cd to goto the real dir (chases any number of symlinks):

Example:

```
c:\> md x
c:\> mklink /d x y 
c:\> cd y
c:\y> mosh_realdir2.cmd
c:\x>
```

$ cat mosh_realdir2.cmd

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('bash mosh_realdir1.sh .') do call set PWD_REAL0=%%a
:: change bash slash to backslash for cmd
set PWD_REAL1=!PWD_REAL0:/=\
 cd /d !PWD_REAL1!
```

needs cygwin bash to chase backlinks:

$ cat mosh_realdir1.sh

```
USAGE="
What: Resolve symlinked dir to realdir, by going up the dirs.
Usage: $0 symdir or pwd   .. prints realdir -> symdir by back chasing links.
Also see: namei.exe 
GPL(C) linkedin.com/in/moshahmed
"
 
if [[ .$1 == .-h ]] ;then
  echo  "$USAGE"
  exit
fi

NAME=$(cygpath -wam .)
case $NAME in *\ *) NAME="$(cygpath -dasm .)" ;; esac # 8.3 name if has space.
# echo $NAME
# Go up the tree to Drive: if (DIR != PREV) NAME =~ s/$PREV/$SYN/
while true ;do
  PREV=$DIR
  DIR=$(cygpath -wam .) 
  case $DIR in *\ *) DIR="$(cygpath -dasm .)" ;; esac # shorten name if spaces.
  if [[ ( -n "$PREV" ) && !( $PREV =~ $DIR* ) ]] ;then
    SYM=$DIR/${PREV##*/}
    NAME=$(echo $NAME | perl -lpe "s,$PREV,$SYM,")
    # echo $NAME
  fi
  case $DIR in [A-Z]:/ | [A-Z]:/cyg* | / ) break ;; esac # TOPLEVEL
  cd $DIR/.. # Go up one level
done
echo $NAME
```